# How do I construct a compound cssSelector for WebDriver?

Tags: css, selenium

I have HTML code that requires I identify a yes/no button text using a compound `cssSelector` in WD:

```
ele = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id*='governmentProperty'][div:not(.ui-state-active)][span.ui-button-text]"));
```

But this syntax doesn't work. I was told by a developer to use this:

```
[id$=governmentProperty] div:not(.ui-state-active) span.ui-button-text
```

but he admits he knows nothing about WD so I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax for this compound `cssSelector` using WD.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried to use that CSS selector the developer proposed?

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTML?

Comment: WebDriver will do nothing special with CSS selectors, so what he has suggested to you is perfectly fine. You are expected to use CSS selectors that conform to the CSS selector specification with WebDriver.